# Phonegap debug on iOS Device need unplug/plug to work

Tags: ios, debugging, cordova, compilation

I have a problem which is really boring.

When I use the command `phonegap run ios` on my Mac, I always need to unplug / plug again my device about 5s before the end of compilation, or it won't work.

When it doesn't work, I have this error :

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

------ Install phase ------
[....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[  0%] Found device (8879a32aa84069dc4cb8a9fb1bacfb1961057db3), beginning install
Assertion failed: (AMDeviceStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.afc"), &afcFd, NULL) == 0), function handle_device, file ios-deploy.c, line 775.
/Users/tchazalet/Desktop/ma-cagnotte-mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/run: line 138: 81212 Abort trap: 6           ios-deploy -d -b "$DEVICE_APP_PATH"
```

Is there is a way to avoid this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried PhoneGap's new [developer app](http://app.phonegap.com/) ?

Comment: Looks interesting, but it requires to use something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by random.

Simply needs to open Xcode and let it open. It will maintain the connection alive to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to click the "eject" button on iTunes if it's open and then close iTunes. Having iTunes open and the phone connected to iTunes will cause this issue.